# How to create an array of pointers inside a function whose size is not known till run time

Tags: c++, arrays, function, pointers, multidimensional-array

In main I can:

```
Node* myNodeArray2[myHeight][myWidth];//Does not call constructor

for(int i=0; i<myHeight; i++){
    for(int j=0; j<myWidth; j++){
        theNodeArray[i][j] = new Node("ThisIsTest", 5, 5);
    }
}
```

So for the above code myHeight and myWidth can be user input at run time. It does not call the default constructor and I can use the new operator and go through the array creating the objects.

I want to be able to pass Node* myNodeArray2 to a function and let it create the array size and populate it. When it is created I want the elements to be pointers. I don't want to call the default constructor. I want to be able to at my choosing call the new operator with the non-default constructor.

When I try:

```
void Test(Node*& theNodeArray, int myHeight, int myWidth){
    theNodeArray = new Node*[myHeight][myWidth];

}

int main(){
    Node* myNodeArray;
    Test(myNodeArray, myHeight, myWidth);

}
```

I get that

> "myWidth is not a constant expression."

I have tried a couple of different methods but cannot get what I want. I need the creation to happen in a separate function. I need to be able to define the size at runtime. Any help?

Edit:

I don't want to use std::vector.

Edit 2:

I don't want to do this

```
int** ary = new int*[sizeX];
for(int i = 0; i < sizeX; ++i)
    ary[i] = new int[sizeY];
```

As this forces the rows to be of objects of contiguous memory space. I want to allocate a 2d array of pointers. I do not want to necessarily create the objects that will be pointed to.

Comment: Why don't you want to use a `vector`?

Comment: Code will be used in a C to gates custom HDL that does not support vector.

Comment: If you can't use [tag:c++], change tag to [tag:c].

Comment: Can use a mixture. It is a custom C to Gate compiler. Not mine, just using it as I was told for this project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the following:

```
Node*** MakeArrayNodePtr(int myHeight, int myWidth){
    Node*** res = new Node**[myHeight];
    for (int i = 0; i != myHeight; ++i) {
        res[i] = new Node*[myWidth]();
    }
    return res;
}
```

And don't forget

```
void DeleteArrayNodePtr(Node*** nodes, int myHeight, int myWidth)
{
    for (int i = 0; i != myHeight; ++i) {
        // And probably:
        /*
        for (int j = 0; j != myWidth; ++j) {
            delete nodes[i][j];
        }
        */
        delete [] nodes[i];
    }
    delete [] nodes;
}
```